# I cannot connect to my local MySQL server from the MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The following is the error I get whenever I try to connect to my local MySQL server as the root user (via the workbench):

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)

This has been an issue on my work laptop for a very long time. The following are the specifics of this problem:

The connection type I am attempting is TCP/IP.

The operating system I am using is Windows 10.

I used the MSI MySQL installer to install the application.

The skip_networking value is set to False.

The bind_address value is set to *.

I can connect to my local MySQL server from the MySQL workbench when I have just install the MySQL Server on my local computer. However, I become permanently locked out upon restarting my system just once (the same password no longer works). This is the only way I have been able to access the workbench (having to delete and reinstall the MySQL server every time)

I have made sure that the MySQL server is in fact running on 127.0.0.1:3306 and that there are no connection errors when I ping it.

It seems that I can connect to the MySQL server as the root user from the command line (using the same password).

It doesn't seem that resetting the root user password works. Resetting the root password sometimes even causes more problems as I occasionally stop being able to connect to the MySQL server even from the command line. I have already tested the following commands so far with no results (and many more that I don't remember):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('password') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

```
UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('password'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I would appreciate any insight to this problem

Comment: I suggest looking at the connection that is configured for Mysql Workbench (and can you post that here, ***-out any sensitive passwords or IP). Is *that* using the ip 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I tried changing the root user authentication string. The new password works in the command line, but still outputs the same error over at the workbench.

Comment: weren't you referring to the command you gave earlier? ALTER USER USER() IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';

Comment: The output of SELECT Host, User, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root;  is localhost, root, caching_sha2_password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252125/discussion-between-nnichols-and-amin-parvaresh).

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I know that I've had issues similar to this - but I don't seem to have made a note of how I resolved/ixed it.   :/   If you happen to share the resolution I'd appreciate it! Best regards!

Comment: @PeteKelley I wasn't able to resolve the issue beyond having to uninstall and reinstall the MySQL server on my system upon every use. I've kind of given up at this point.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out there were multiple instances of the MySQL server running on port 3306, and I believe that the workbench was attempting to connect to one as opposed to the other.

Once I ended those MySQL tasks from the task manager and restarted the local MySQL server from windows services settings, it was all golden.

Comment: Multiple instances on the same port? That sounds pretty strange. Shouldn't the server complain about this on startup?